# Face recognition in R

Tags: r, face-recognition

Are there any face recognition algorithms written in the R statistical language?  If not, please provide guidance on where I might start translating other algorithms to R.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Be sure to check out the update made on May 8, 2013. See below.**

Here are a few links/thoughts to get you started:

1. Does it have to be in R? (There are other languages/packages that are inherently more suitable for image processing.
2. If R is mandatory, look into the **[EBImage](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/EBImage/html/00Index.html)** (it has a [pdf vignette](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/EBImage/doc/AnalysisWithEBImage.pdf)) and **[raster](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/)** packages. (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/)
3. ***Where's Waldo?*** type exercises are always a good place to start if you are new to image processing. Here are is one [R question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563604/how-to-find-waldo-with-r)
4. [Here's an actual R example](http://is-r.tumblr.com/post/36874307174/finding-a-bright-object) that you will find really useful: "Finding a bright object" exercise in **in.R()**
5. Even though it is not in R *per se* read the [responses to `image-processing` using mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479058/how-do-i-find-waldo-with-mathematica) question in SO. Some of the ideas there are language-agnostic.

**Update**

- R's `ReadImages` package is another good way to get started with "Image Processing with R."

  - Install the ReadImages package from cran. [Documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ReadImages/ReadImages.pdf)
  - Try out a couple of the functions, with some image on your machine. That's only way to learn.

    `img <- read.jpeg("abc.jpg)`  Try out the `rgb2grey(img)`
    Also try the `clipping()` function.

**Update 2: May 08, 2013**

Kaggle has just [published an excellent tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/c/facial-keypoints-detection/details/getting-started-with-r) for Face Recognition in R (by [James Petterson](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~jpetterson/)).  It has many things going for it: A sample dataset, it doesn't use many esoteric libraries -- just reshape2 and doMC (optional unless you have a multi-core machine).

The Kaggle tutorial covers the idea of facepoints (left_eyebrow, nose tip etc), the idea of a 'mean' location for features and the concept of using image patches to improve recognition.
I cannot think of a better link for this question. [Be sure to check it out](https://www.kaggle.com/c/facial-keypoints-detection/details/getting-started-with-r).

Hope these help you get started.