# Facial Recognition in R

Tags: algorithm, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Face recognition in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105379/face-recognition-in-r)

Has anyone created any facial recognition programs in R? I'm working on a rough version of one, but wanted to see if anything else was out there.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but it's certainly possible the link that Robinson found will be your best answer.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I was specifically looking for something similar to the eigenface method of Turk - mainly want to apply the same method to vectors, not necessarily images.

Comment: @DWin, said link asks the exact same question, but phrases it "I am looking for face Recognition in R project."