# How to get rectangles around the objects in the image?

Tags: c#, image, rectangles

what would be the easiest way to programmatically get the rectangles around the objects in the image? looking for a solution in c#

[image]

i'm not entirely sure how to approach the search for this. any hints are highly welcome.

*edit: 
As Bobby guessed correctly, I'm trying to find the surrounding rectangles around the blobs. The spots vary in size and shape and position. They could be star shaped and round for instance. As TaW stated I would need to figure out what pixels are connected to each other. How would you deal with holes?

best wishes

Comment: I can't see any rectangle around objects. What do you mean by *rectangles around the objects*?

Comment: He wants to draw rectangles around the red blobs

Comment: What are you using to make the drawings?

Comment: What is the input? Image? or you have some other representation as obejcts?

Comment: How much work do you want to put into this? What do you know about the images and how they will vary, esp. in terms of the number of colors? Besides looking for a library you'll have to scan the raster of pixels to find a list of changes and then work throught those changes to identify those that are connected..

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! Chase Ernst: I'm using c# with unity to generate a texture2d. Sriram Sakthivel The input image are basically two different images substracted from another to figure out the differences. But I want to basically work with the spots further on and try to figure out a way to get the frame around them.

Comment: As you stated, your first task is to determine your algorithm for defining a contiguous image (a blob). Once you have that, determine the size of margin (2px, 3px, etc) you want around the blob. Then the remaining question is what technology do you want to use? Are you using WinForm or WPF? Both have different drawing libraries and I would highly recommend against GDI for WinForms. You also have the option of drawing with OpenGL ...and doesn't Unity have a drawing library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach could be

1. scan the image for a red pixel
2. perform a [FloodFill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) keeping track of the min/max x and y for successful colour replacements ... when the fill finishes you have one bounding box. Plus you have eliminated all red pixels for that blob
3. goto 1 and resume scanning

Comment: this is what i end up with thanks :) for everyone else who is curious: https://github.com/kibotu/net.kibotu.sandbox.unity.spotthedifference/blob/master/unity/Assets/Sources/FloodFill.cs

Answer (score 1):

This is simplified question of **[Find Waldo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479058/how-do-i-find-waldo-with-mathematica)** assuming you can call Wolfram language in C#.net. I do not have Wolfram on this computer, but it should be something like:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlVlM.png"];
objectshape = SelectComponents[DeleteBorderComponents[Binarize[img, {0, .7}]], "Area"}, 10 < #1 < 1000 && #2 > 0 &];
shapes = ComponentMeasurements[ImageMultiply[img, objectshape], {"BoundingBoxArea"}][[All, 2]];
Show[img, Graphics[{Red, Thick, Rectangle @@ # & /@ shapes}]]
```

Very similar result, what i based my answer on : [segmentation analysis](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/AnalyzeSegmentedCellsInAnImage.html)

Comment: This might be useful http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19516/load-a-mathematica-package-via-net-code

Comment: well i'm sure this works just fine however for this single task i don't think it's appriate to include the entire wolfram library into unity ^^' but thanks for recommending this though i might have further use for it in the future :)