# How to get a position of custom object on image using vision recognition api

Tags: computer-vision, image-recognition, object-detection

I know there is a lot of vision recognition APIs such as Clarifai, Watson, Google Cloud Vision, Microsoft Cognitive Services which provide recognition of image content. The response of these services is simple json that contains different tags, for example

```
{ 
   man: 0.9969295263290405,
   portrait: 0.9949591159820557,
   face: 0.9261120557785034
}
```

The problem is that I need to know not only what is on the image but also the position of that object. Some of those APIs have such feature but only for face detection.

So does anyone know if there is such API or I need to train own haar cascades on OpenCV for every object.

I will be very greatful for sharing some info.

Comment: You might find the [Ciliar API](https://ciliar.co) useful. It can do object recognition for both images and videos (disclaimer I run it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at Wolfram Cloud/Mathematica.

It has the ability to detect object locations in a picture.

Some examples.

- [Detecting road signs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11725/how-to-find-circular-objects-in-an-image).
- [Finding Waldo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479058/how-do-i-find-waldo-with-mathematica).
- [Object tracking in video](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/advanced-image-processing-with-large-image-support/tracking-objects-in-an-image-sequence.html).

Comment: It seems too complicated for me. Besides, I would like something with Java support, because my project is in Java. But thanks anyway)

Comment: Both Wolfram and Mathematica support Java.

Comment: oh, sorry, didn't see that. I'll take a look at that once more