# Template matching in Android Opencv

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, opencv, image-processing

I a working on a project in which i need to match the two images i-e; the image captured through camera is to be matched with the one of the images in database on server. Can anyone help please. I am new with android and opencv.

Comment: Have a look at [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479058/how-do-i-find-waldo-with-mathematica/43344275#43344275)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too broad of a question to answer directly - but hopefully I can provide a couple resources you can dive into to learn specifically how to do the few things your asking for.

Introduction to OpenCV for Android:

https://opencv.org/platforms/android/

GitHub project implementing what I think you're asking for:

https://github.com/torcellite/imageComparator